# streamBuilder not updating itsself after sorting or filtering - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, provider

I am using StreamBuilder and ListView to show data from FireStoreDatabase in UI. Usually, it updates itself when I make any change in the database (without refresh). but when I sort the data in the stream, it no longer updates. here's the code am using for StreamBuilder.

```
Stream<List<Attraction>> attractionsStream = Stream.value([]);

void initState() {
    final database = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
     setState(() {
          //this.attractions = attractions.toList();
          attractionsStream = database.attractionStream();
        });
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<List<Attraction>>(
      stream: attractionsStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {...}
    );
  }

_sortData() async {
    final db = Provider.of<Database>(context, listen: false);
    var attractions = await db.attractionStream().first;
    attractions.sort((a, b) {...}
    setState(() {
      attractionsStream = Stream.value(attractions);
    });
    }
```

Could you please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unique `Key` to each widget that your StreamBuilder builds.

It is also uncommon to completely reset the stream, as opposed to pushing new data through the stream already in use.

Comment: I tried to use `key` but it didn't work.

Could you recommend some other way of changing data?

Comment: Your use of streams looks off. Instead of re-assigning the stream, you want to push new data through the existing stream. Try `myStreamController.sink.add(data)` instead of creating a new stream.

Comment: I tried to use that too but after adding it doesn’t update itself

Comment: We would need to see your updated code :)